# ios/safari universal link in address bar support

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I have question about what is the best way to handle url user typed in ios/safari address bar. We have univerasal links support for our app and we want to handle properly url in safari's address bar. It means when user types https://app.domain.com/#/somecode then system should open App Store if our app is not installed and open our app if it installed.
Are there any ways to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is impossible, because of the way Universal Links currently are implemented.**

The closest you can get is sending the user to a landing page with a button that has a Universal Link behind it (on a *different* domain than the landing page). Of course, this means users who *click* on a link will also be shown the landing page (in addition to those who type the URL into the address bar).